# I created an Amplify App via the console but I am unable to pull it

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I created a Reactjs NextJS app in the Amplify console, and I am trying to pull it. I did have some problems initially because I am using `AWS SSO` to sign in, but after using [aws-export-credentials](https://github.com/benkehoe/aws-export-credentials) I was able to get around that exporting credentials to a new profile, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

My app is having a front-end only, but when I try to pull it, it complains that no backend exists.

```
Cannot find any backend environment in the Amplify Console App next-app.
Failed to pull the backend.
Cannot find any backend environment in the Amplify Console App next-app.
Error: Cannot find any backend environment in the Amplify Console App next-app.
    at getBackendEnv (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/attach-backend.js:297:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/attach-backend.js:76:22)
    at Object.attachBackend (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/index.ts:50:3)
    at Object.queryProvider (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/attach-backend-steps/a10-queryProvider.ts:12:3)
    at Object.attachBackend (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/attach-backend.ts:20:5)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/commands/pull.ts:59:5)
    at Object.executeAmplifyCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/index.ts:373:5)
    at executePluginModuleCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/execution-manager.ts:178:3)
    at Object.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/execution-manager.ts:30:5)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/index.ts:205:5)
```

I will otherwise make the app from the cli instead but still wanting to understand why this has happened.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No ): I actually ended up using an older version of amplify so I could do this. I didn't need 99% of the functionality, simply hosting an s3 SPA with cloudfront.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by deleting and recreating the app from the CLI.